# Angularjs UI Grid switch column icon

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, grid, ui-grid

I am use UI Grid to draw a table.

Here is UI Grid offical webiste:
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/215_treeView

Now, I want to switch collapse icon and selectAll icon.

By default UI Grid, the collapse is first element, selectAll Icon is second element.
I want to switch of them.

[image]

Here is the sample

http://embed.plnkr.co/DODIxKaQ5nrqNO9eUObe/

Anyone can help with this ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible, yet...  you might want to add your vote here...

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4862

I just added my two cents worth.

Comment: Thanks very much for your link.